# Simply connected 3-manifolds are homotopy equivalent to 3-spheres

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homotopy-theory, spheres

Let $M$ be a simply connected $3$-dimensional manifold (smooth, closed, connected). How to prove that $M$ has a homotopy type of a $3$-sphere?
I would like to use somehow Whitehead theorem: so the problem reduces to show the *weak* homotopy equivalence (i.e. the existence of a map $f:M \to S^3$ inducing isomorphisms on every homotopy group).

Comment: I think this is a pretty hard problem.  You might check out the literature on it.

Comment: Poincare conjecture?

Comment: @TakahiroWaki homotopy equivalence is weaker than homeomorphism.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By Poincaré duality, $H_2(M)=0$ (use universal coefficient theorem). Applying Hurewicz, we get that $M$ is $2$-connected and that the Hurewicz map $h:\pi_3(M)\to H_3(M)\cong\mathbb{Z}$ is an isomorphism. Letting $f:S^3\to M$ represent a generator of $\pi_3(M)$, we see that $f$ is a homotopy equivalence by Whitehead (using the fact that manifolds are homotopy equivalent to CW complexes).

This is exercise 4.2.15 in Hatcher.

Comment: I know this is old but I have a question: why can we use Poincare duality if we aren't assuming in the statement of the question that M is orientable?

Comment: Simply connected manifolds are always orientable (consider the orientation double cover)

Comment: In order to use Whitehead's theorem we need $f$ to induce isomorphisms on all homotopy groups. The steps here give isomorphisms for 0,1,2,3; but what about higher homotopy groups?

Comment: Good point, I must have missed that

Comment: @RS: there is another version of Whitehead for simply connected spaces, that only depends on homology isomorphisms.